# Symbian - Does s60 version 5 app work on s60 version 1

Tags: version, symbian, compatibility

I build an app for my company using Symbian s60 SDK version 5.
My question is will it run on phones with Symbian s60 version 1 OS or not?

(I am aware that reverse compatibility may not work, but just for clarification I posted this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not, absolutely not. In fact, S60 v1 is not even backwards compatible with v5 (there was a major binary compatibility break at S60 3rd edition).

If you need S60 v1, you have some work to do - there are many breaks and API changes to deal with.

If you want to increase market coverage, you can build on S60 3rd edition which will give you compatibility with S60 5th edition.

Comment: Unless @Satyam sw meant Symbian^1 instead of S60 1.x. Symbian^1 is essentially the same as S60 5th Edition and therefore binary compatible.

Comment: Good point. @Satyam - did you Mean S60 1st Edition, or Symbian^1? They are very different.